# Transferring Print Jobs Between Printers

Tags: c#, printing

We are assigned to develop an application using C# that can transfer print jobs between printers. I have looked on the Windows API, and System.Printing namespace but I can't find a class or function that can do this. Is there a free library out there that is suitable for this? How will you do this using .Net or the Win32 API?

Answer (score 4):

If nothing exists in the Win32 API, then there will be nothing in .NET.

Unless the printer drivers are *identical* then you may have problems because the printer jobs go through some processing by the driver before entering the queue.

Have you considered a single queue with multiple printers associated with it (this giving more capacity and redundancy in case of printer failure)?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a problem of load-balancing/routing a particular job to the least busy printer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just CopyFile a SPL file to a new printer port if it's the same driver. If you print in EMF, you may be able to go across different drivers.

The port names might be a bit tricky depending on how the printer(s) are attached. WinObj and [the rules of dev naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx) will be handy for tracking it down.