PrintQueueWatch library PrintJob.Transfer
I'm getting access denied when I try to use the function
PrintJob.Transfer
using (PrinterQueueWatch.PrinterInformation PrinterInfo = new PrinterQueueWatch.PrinterInformation("HP LaserJet P1006", PrinterQueueWatch.SpoolerApiConstantEnumerations.PrinterAccessRights.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS, true))
                {                    
                    PrinterInfo.PrintJobs.get_ItemByJobId(Id).Transfer("Microsoft Print to PDF", false);                    
                }

using (PrinterQueueWatch.PrinterInformation PrinterInfo = new PrinterQueueWatch.PrinterInformation("HP LaserJet P1006", PrinterQueueWatch.SpoolerApiConstantEnumerations.PrinterAccessRights.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS, true))
                {                    
                    PrinterInfo.PrintJobs.get_ItemByJobId(Id).Transfer("Microsoft Print to PDF", false);       

         
            }


please show always the fukk error trace it has much more details

PrintQueueWatch is a library for monitoring PrintQueue and PrintJobs, the function Transfer is for Transfer a PrintJob that is been Printing in another Printer, the objective is make a copy of the PrintJob using the printer Microsoft Print to PDF, i created an instance of the Printer that has the printJob witch administrative permission, but it seems that is not enough, because I'm getting an exception that says access denied, that all it's says.

transfer would only work if you have identical drivers, but you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560317/transferring-print-jobs-between-printers but i never done that
